# Table name limit in SQLite Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, limit

Probably I'm giving a little bit trivial question but I'm wondering that is there any limit for table name or field name in SQLite especially in Android. As I good remember there was or still is simillar problem in Oracle Database.

Comment: I think [these](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) are the only limitations in sqlite. Please go through it.

Comment: The official docs are the best resource, though in general SQLite is very loose when it comes to limits, so in most cases you don't need to worry. Whether or not it's a good decision to use 32 KB names or a billion tables is another matter. Keep in mind that just because SQLite limits are lax, you may need to migrate your data to another system or application which may be a lot more strict.

Answer (score 8):

I think that there is no a limit itself for the table name. But it depends on the maximum length of the SQL Statement. By default it is 1000000.

You can check it at http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 3):

No particular limitation in the sqlite documentation but

- Use name between 1 to 128 byte
- Start with a letter
- Avoid SQL reserved words
- Avoid space

Comment: why ? If there is no limitation, why restrict to 128 byte ?

Comment: I create a table with name 9090909090_89898989898 and it gave me this exception 01-30 01:49:00.859: E/AndroidRuntime(30731): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "9090909090_89898989898" (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 9090909090_89898989898 (_id  NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, ts  NUMERIC, from  TEXT, to  TEXT, message  TEXT, status  TEXT)

Comment: @Redwarp Best practice, though it depends on your application or spoken language (for multi-byte encodings or dialects with longer words, 128 may not be enough). But in general, names should be short and clear. Plus it's more compatible with other DB systems that may have stricter limits.